# Genotype as input, give the phenotype

Tags: python, beginner, parsing

I want to write a Python script where the input is a genotype (e.g. "CCDd") based upon the following [Punnett square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punnett_square). The output should be the phenotype (e.g. "seal").

[image]

My code works, but doesn't look that 'pythonic' at all.

```
def colour(input):

    if len(set(input)) == 2 and input[0] != 'C' and input[2] != 'D':
        return('lilac')
    elif len(set(input[2::])) == 1 and input[2] != 'D':
        return('blue')
    elif len(set(input[0:2])) == 1 and input[0] != 'C':
        return('chocolate')
    else:
        return('seal')
```

Answer (score 6):

You correctly identified that you need to count the number of lowercase `c` and `d`. But using a `set` to do so is not the right tool. Instead, I suggest using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter


def color(genotype):
    assert len(genotype) == 4

    count = Counter(genotype)
    blue = count['d'] == 2
    chocolate = count['c'] == 2

    if blue and chocolate:
        return 'lilac'
    if blue:
        return 'blue'
    if chocolate:
        return 'chocolate'
    return 'seal'
```

I also added a [debug check](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) to ensure that the length of the input sequence is always four.

---

Given the mini debate that occured in the comments, pertaining to variable names, you may consider this slight variation:

```
from collections import Counter


def color(genotype):
    assert len(genotype) == 4

    count = Counter(genotype)
    recessive_traits = [count[gene] == 2 for gene in 'cd']

    if all(recessive_traits):
        return 'lilac'
    if recessive_traits[0]:
        return 'blue'
    if recessive_traits[1]:
        return 'chocolate'
    return 'seal'
```

It *may* be more expressive as to what you're testing, and why.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the existince of the collections.counter, I also never used an if statement with just one argument. Am I correct if I say that 'if blue:' means 'if blue exists:'?

Comment: `if x:` is exactly the same than `if bool(x) == True:`. Whatever `x` is. Except it's cleaner.

Comment: I'm not sure if I like `blue` and `chocolate` as names, because they don't represent blueness or chocolateness (at least for me, blueness and chocolateness does not imply lilacness).

Comment: maybe... they convey the booleanness. But maybe someone with expert knowledge about the topic (so, not me) would agree with `blue` and `chocolate`.

Comment: not overly python but you could index the bools to a list,

ans = ['seal', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'lilac']

return ans[2*chocolate + blue]

Comment: @Jasper Provided an alternate solution. I feel it better convey what is being tested. What do you think?

Comment: Would it make sense to call `blue` `dd` and `chocolate` `cc`? Then `dd` is clearly for "there are two 'd alleles'" and the `if` "adds meaning": if there are two d alleles, the thing is blue. I hope that makes enough sense for the biological experts :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted produces nonsense results for incorrectly formatted input:

```
>>> colour('DDCC')
'lilac'
>>> colour('abcdef')
'seal'
>>> colour('aayx')
'chocolate'
```

It would be better if the function rejected such inputs by [raising an appropriate exception](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225956/python-assert-vs-if-return/225958#225958). I advise [against using assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944592/best-practice-for-python-assert/945135#945135) for this purpose, for the reasons discussed in the two links.

I suggest to separate the two tasks of parsing the genotype from the input string and determining the phenotype based on the presence of the dominant allele for each of the two genes.

(The same suggestion is essentially also contained in Mathias Ettinger's answer, however I interpret the "blueness" and "chocolateness" inversely, so that *blue and chocolate* gives *seal*, and *neither blue nor chocolate* gives *lilac*.)

As an alternative style of coding the phenotype logic, I have chosen a lookup table using a dictionary.

Validating and parsing the input can be combined in a single step using a regular expression.

Also note that I have added a docstring to the function, which includes a few [doctests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) that can automatically be checked.

```
import re

def colour(genotype):
    """Determine the phenotype given the genotype encoded as a four-letter
    string consisting of two C's ("blueness" gene) followed by two D's
    ("chocolateness" gene) where the capitalization of the letters indicates
    whether the dominant (upper-case) or recessive (lower-case) alleles are
    present.

    >>> colour('CCDD')
    'seal'
    >>> colour('CCdd')
    'blue'
    >>> colour('ccDd')
    'chocolate'
    >>> colour('ccdd')
    'lilac'
    >>> colour('abcde')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ValueError: Incorrectly formatted input: abcde
    """

    def has_dominant(alleles):
        # Aa, aA, AA -> True, aa -> False
        return not alleles.islower()

    try:
        blue, chocolate = map(has_dominant,
            re.match(r'^([Cc]{2})([Dd]{2})$', genotype).groups())
    except AttributeError:
        raise ValueError('Incorrectly formatted input: {}'.format(genotype))

    return {
        (True,  True):  'seal',
        (True,  False): 'blue',
        (False, True):  'chocolate',
        (False, False): 'lilac'}[
        (blue,  chocolate)]
```